# Table should have real width

Tags: html, html-table, width

I have a table:

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:200px">td1</td>
        <td style="width:3200px">td2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the browser fits it in the current window, in it's width proportions I think.
I would like the table to have it's real width, so that the window scrolls if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the table behaves this way - upvotes from me for anybody who can explain in depth why the width on the `td`s gets overridden.

The easiest way around it would be giving the `table` element the composite width:

```
<table style="width: 3400px">
```

alternatively, putting a 3200px wide element into the `td` seems to work as well:

```
<td style="width:3200px"><div style="width: 3200px">&nbsp;</div></td>
```

Comment: Great, the idea with the nested div achieves my goal.

Answer (score 1):

TD widths are always interpreted as percentages in relation to the width of the entire table when the table does not overflow anymore. Tables do not overflow past the horizontal edge unless they have an explicit width set.

```
<table border="1px" width="3400px"> <!--The page will overflow if the table width is greater -->
  <tr>
   <td style="width:200px">td1</td>
   <td>td2</td> <!--The width of this cell will be whatever 3400-200 is. (i.e. 3200) -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: overflow: scroll seems not to work. I cannot set an explicit width, is there perhaps a workaround?

Comment: @Jan-Frederik Carl My first thought is making a script that sets the width value of the table based on the sum of the width values of the cells.